# Need help understanding how gsub and tonumber are used to encode lua source code?

Tags: encryption, encoding, lua

I'm new to LUA but figured out that gsub is a global substitution function and tonumber is a converter function. What I don't understand is how the two functions are used together to produce an encoded string.

I've already tried reading parts of PIL (Programming in Lua) and the reference manual but still, am a bit confused.

```
local L0_0, L1_1
function L0_0(A0_2)
  return (A0_2:gsub("..", function(A0_3)
    return string.char((tonumber(A0_3, 16) + 256 - 13 + 255999744) % 256)
  end))
end
encodes = L0_0
L0_0 = gg
L0_0 = L0_0.toast
L1_1 = "__loading__\226\128\166"
L0_0(L1_1)
L0_0 = encodes
L1_1 = --"The Encoded String"
L0_0 = L0_0(L1_1)
L1_1 = load
L1_1 = L1_1(L0_0)
pcall(L1_1)
```

I removed the encoded string where I put the comment because of how long it was. If needed I can upload the encoded string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` is being used to get 2 digit sections of `A0_2`. This means the string `A0_3` is a 2 digit hexadecimal number but it is not in a number format so we cannot preform math on the value. `A0_3` being a hex number can be inferred based on how `tonubmer` is used.

`tonumber` from [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html):

> Tries to convert its argument to a number. If the argument is already a number or a string convertible to a number, then tonumber returns this number; otherwise, it returns nil.
>
> An optional argument specifies the base to interpret the numeral. The base may be any integer between 2 and 36, inclusive. In bases above 10, the letter 'A' (in either upper or lower case) represents 10, 'B' represents 11, and so forth, with 'Z' representing 35. In base 10 (the default), the number can have a decimal part, as well as an optional exponent part (see §2.1). In other bases, only unsigned integers are accepted.

So `tonumber(A0_3, 16)` means we are expecting for `A0_3` to be a base 16 number (hexadecimal).
Once we have the number value of `A0_3` we do some math and finally convert it to a character.

```
function L0_0(A0_2)
  return (A0_2:gsub("..", function(A0_3)
        return string.char((tonumber(A0_3, 16) + 256 - 13 + 255999744) % 256)
      end))
end
```

This block of code takes a string of hex digits and converts them into chars. tonumber is being used to allow for the manipulation of the values.

Here is an example of how this works with `Hello World`:

```
local str = "Hello World"
local hex_str = ''

for i = 1, #str do
    hex_string = hex_string .. string.format("%x", str:byte(i,i))
end

function L0_0(A0_2)
  return (A0_2:gsub("..", function(A0_3)
    return string.char((tonumber(A0_3, 16) + 256 - 13 + 255999744) % 256)
  end))
end

local encoded = L0_0(hex_str)
print(encoded)
```

Output

> ;X__bJbe_W

And taking it back to the orginal string:

```
function decode(A0_2)
  return (A0_2:gsub("..", function(A0_3)
    return string.char((tonumber(A0_3, 16) + 13) % 256)
  end))
end

hex_string = ''
for i = 1, #encoded do
    hex_string = hex_string .. string.format("%x", encoded:byte(i,i))
end

print(decode(hex_string))
```